# How C# public void static Main(String[] args){} and public int static Main(String[] args) two overloaded method work together?

Tags: c#, .net

How CLR knows which method to call since they are returning different value(One is void and another is int) ? In sense of Overloading this is also not right, a method with same parameter with different return type.

example:

```
class Program
{
    static int Main(String[] args) //Main with int return type but Parameter String[] args
    {
            return 0;
    }

    /* this main method also gonna get called by CLR even though return type void  and Same parameter String[] args.
   static void Main(String[] args) //Main with int return type but String[] args
   {

   } */

    private static void func(int one)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(one);
    }

    private static int func(int one) //compiler error. two overloaded method cant have same parameter and different return type. 
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

but main method is not maintaining overloading rules.

Comment: Please provide a code sample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in .NET, an executable can have only one entry point i.e. only one Main method is allowed. To be more specific, the Main method is considered as an entry point only if the sigature matches any of the below 2 and the method is static.

1. Main(String[])
2. Main()

If, you provide a main method whose signature is different from above two, it is not considered as Main method. So, below code is allowed,

```
class Program
{
    static void Main ()          //Entry point
    {
    } 

    static void Main(int number)
    {
    }
}
```

The below code doesn't compile because, it finds matching signature at two places.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main ()          //Entry point
    {
    } 

    static void Main(String[] args)   //another entrypoint!!! Compile Error
    {
    }
}
```

Below code also doesn't compile because there is no entry point at all,

```
class Program
{
    static void Main (int a)      //Not an Entry point 
    {
    } 

    static void Main(float b)    //Not an entry point
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, just in general, when overloading, the methods must differ in more than just return type.